# Assuming secp256k1 curve and given fixed (but random) $h$ and $d$ values, is it possible to calculate a $k$ such that $h\equiv(k\,G)_X\,(k-d)\pmod n$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, cryptocurrency

For generator point $G$ in the [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsection.2.4) curve, I want to find a value $k$ such that:
$$h\equiv(k\,G)_X\,(k-d)\pmod n$$
where $n$ is the group order, and $(k\,G)_X$ indicates the x-coordinate (mod n) of the resulting point after the multiplication by $k$. Assume $h$ and $d$ are fixed scalar values that I've been given.

Is it possible to calculate $k$?

Without the multiplication by $(k - d)$, this would just be the ECC discrete log problem. Does having that extra multiplication make it easier to calculate some $k$, or is there a way to show that it still reduces to the discrete log problem?

In my experiments with smaller fields, it appears that no such $k$ value exists about 35% of the time.

Comment: I'd be surprised is this was sizably easier than the DLP, and would not be surprised if it was much harder: I fail to think of a $\mathcal O(\sqrt n\,\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n)))$ algorithm to solve this, when there are for the DLP.

Comment: @fgrieu I was actually hoping as much. It would be nice to have a proof that it's at least as hard, but it certainly makes sense intuition-wise. Thanks.

Comment: cross-posted [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4504216/338051)

Comment: Once more, $(kG)_X$ is only well defined modulo $p$. It is not well defined modulo $n$.